# Multiple GET() methods with a single parameter result in AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
{
}

[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<string> Get([FromRoute]int id)
{
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()([FromQuery]DateTime dateTime)
{
}
```

I can reach the second with:

```
https://localhost:44341/api/Orders/3
```

But for the first and third:

```
https://localhost:44341/api/Orders
https://localhost:44341/api/Orders?dateTime=2019-11-01T00:00:00
```

Both of these return the error:

> AmbiguousMatchException

Core 2.2, if it matters.

Comment: If you comment out the first action, does it then work (as a test)?

Comment: @mjwills, yes!  (see edit to OP)

Comment: ok, good catch. I had not gotten that far yet! I'm still trying to work on hitting the various methods.  I adjusted the OP.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the first endpoint and instead use: `[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get([FromQuery]DateTime? dateTime)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just creating a different endpoint for the GetByDate method.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<string> Get()
{
    //
}


[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
{
    //
}


[HttpGet("ByDate/{date}")]
public ActionResult<string> ByDate(DateTime date)
{
    //
}
```

They can be called as follows:

```
https://localhost:44341/api/controller
https://localhost:44341/api/controller/1
https://localhost:44341/api/controller/getbydate/2019-11-01
```

Answer (score 0):

We can have a route at the controller level and handle the string input to parse to int or date as below

```
 [Route("api/[controller]/{id}")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet()]
        public ActionResult<string> Get(string id)
        {

            if (int.TryParse(id, out int result))
            {
                return Ok(id);

            }
            else if (DateTime.TryParse(id, out DateTime result1))
            {
                return Ok(id);
            }
            else
                return Ok("Failed");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thought about this, but it feels like a cheat. Is there no way to have them have separate methods?

Comment: Also, I get `cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.ReadOnlySpan<char>'`

Comment: i dont think we can  have the overloaded methods for this . And for the conversion error , Can you check whether the input parameter is of the type string or notg

Comment: The `id` and `dateTime` endpoints should be different. One returns one entry, one multiple.

Answer (score 0):

How about having Id and date as optional parameters? You can still handle the actual search in a seprate methods if you want, but you have one GET method.

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Get([FromRoute]int? id [FromQuery]DateTime? dateTime)
    {
      if(id.HasValue)
      {
        //Do Something with the id
      } 
      else if (dateTime.HasValue)
      {
        //Do Something with the date
      }
    else 
    {
     //return all
    }
 }
```

Comment: This is perfect go with this. Maybe change the return type to just `IActionResult`.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston When you use IActionResult as a return type, you can return whatever you want

Comment: This is not perfect. As mjwillis said, I need to return different types if we are searching by Id or by Date. If by Id, then we return a single item. If by Date, then we need to return a list of items. I *HAVE* to have these as separate methods.

Comment: @GeorgiGeorgiev "When you use IActionResult as a return type, you can return whatever you want " -- ah, ok. I see. Lemme try this.

Comment: This was close. But `https://localhost:44341/api/Orders/3` returned a 404. See the answer I posted. Thank you for your help!